# How to empty an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, ecmascript-6

I am using ArrayList  as my array,

```
let ArrayList   =  ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
```

I am confused in between Method 1 and Method 2 because in both case I Referenced ArrayList  by another you can also check logs over this link https://jsfiddle.net/mnjsnj/u1fms8wx/2/

Method 1

```
let Method1 = ArrayList;  // Referenced arrayList by another variable 
ArrayList= []; // Empty the array 
console.log(Method1); // Output ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

Method 2

```
let Method2 = ArrayList;  // Referenced arrayList by another variable 
ArrayList.length = 0; // Empty the array by setting length to 0
console.log(Method2 ); // Output []
```

Comment: Initially, both variables reference the same array. Then in the first example a new array is assigned to *ArrayList*, *Method1* is not affected. In the second example, the length of the array that both variables reference is changed.

Comment: Thank you RobG answer is clear now for me

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` is being emptied after first method , so you are assigning an empty array to `Method2`

```js
let ArrayList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

let Method1 = ArrayList; // Referenced arrayList by another variable 
ArrayList = []; // Empty the array 
console.log(Method1); // Output ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

console.log('ArrayList after Method1....!' , ArrayList)
// here an empty array is assinged to Method2
let Method2 = ArrayList; // Referenced arrayList by another variable 
ArrayList.length = 0; // Empty the array by setting length to 0
console.log(Method2); // Output []
```

Comment: Agree with you nice answer thank you

Answer (score 1):

The trick to understanding what is going on here is to understand how variables work in JavaScript and what the assignment (`=`) operator does.

A variable is just a bound name to a memory location.

When we assign something to a variable via the `=` operator, we only change what that variable is pointing to, we are not changing the actual data at the existing memory location, we're just making the variable not point to it anymore.

```
// Method1 now points to the same memory location as ArrayList
let Method1 = ArrayList;
// ArrayList variable now points to a new memory location containing an empty array
ArrayList = []; 
// Method1 is still pointing to the original memory location so the array is unaffected
console.log(Method1);
```

In the second example, you are directly affecting the data at the memory location that `ArrayList` is pointing to by changing its `length` to `0`.

```
// point Method2 variable to the same location as ArrayList variable
let Method2 = ArrayList; 
// change the data stored at the location ArrayList is pointing to
ArrayList.length = 0; // Empty the array by setting length to 0
// Since Method2 is also pointing to that location, we see the empty array
console.log(Method2); // Output []
```

Comment: *"In the case of primitives such as strings or numbers, the value is also copied over when a variable is re-assigned so your code would behave as you expect it."* Uh? If `let ArrayList  = 42` and `let Method1 = ArrayList; ArrayList = 21;`, then `Method1` is still `42`. Variables always work the same way, it doesn't matter what value they have. Or do you mean something else? I guess I'm confused to which code you are referring to. You also say *"since your dealing with an array this works."*, so it seems you are saying in both sentences that "it works".

Comment: @FelixKling I wrote this answer late at night and half-brained haha I've removed that "feels wrong but unsure how" description

Comment: I understand :D